# Two player Tic-tac toe Python program not running completely

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple two player tic-tac toe game but whenever I run it always says its a tie. I can't seem to find the problem with it so I was wondering if someone would assist me in figuring out why it always does that. I've attached the sample code below.

```
import random
import os


def display_board(board):
    print("  |  |")
    print(" " +board[7] + "|" + board[8] + " |" +board[9])
    print("  |  |")
    print(".........")
    print("  |  |")
    print(" " +board[4] + "|" + board[5] + " |" +board[6])
    print("  |  |")
    print(".........")
    print("  |  |")
    print(" " +board[1] + "|" + board[2] + " |" + board[3] )
    print("  |  |")


def choose_player():
    letter = ""
    name1= input("Enter your name Player1: ")
    name2= input("Enter your name Player2: ")
    while(letter !="X" or letter!="O"):     
        letter = input(name1 +"" +"What letter do you want to be?: X or O: ").upper()
        if letter == "X":
            pl={"X":name1,"O":name2}
            print("Player1 is X player2 is O")
            return pl
        elif letter == "O":
            pl={"O":name1,"X":name2}
            print("player1 is O player2 is X")
            return pl
        else:
            errmsg = ["Choose a valid letter", "really?", "You cant be serious"]
            val = random.randint(0,2)
            print(errmsg[val])
def position_board(position,board,letter):

    '''places  input value to a position in list .here name of list is board'''

    board[position] = letter

def winner_check(board,letter):

    '''checks for winner using the conditions of tic tac toe'''

    return (board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == letter or

            board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == letter or

            board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == letter or

            board[1] == board[4] == board[7] == letter or

            board[2] == board[5] == board[8] == letter or

            board[3] == board[6] == board[9] == letter or

            board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == letter or

            board[7] == board[5] == board[3] == letter)

def who_starts():
    if random.randint(0,1) ==1:
        print("player one starts")
        return "X"
    else:
        print("player two starts")
        return "O"

def position_check(board,position):
    if board[position] == "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
def board_full(board,position_check):
    for num in range(1,10):
        if position_check(board,num):
            return False
    else:
        return True

def player_input(board,letter):
    choice = ""
    while(choice not in "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9".split() or  not position_check(board,int(choice))):
          choice = input("{} Choose a number between 1 & 9: ".format(letter))

    return int(choice)


while True:
    board = [" "]*10
    game_on = True
    name = choose_player()
    turn= who_starts()
    while game_on:
        if turn == "X":
            display_board(board)
            board_status=board_full(board,position_check)
            if winner_check(board, "O"):
                print("congrats {} is the winner".format(name["0"]))
                break
            if board_status:
                print("you tied")
                break
            position = player_input(board,name["X"])
            position_status = position_check(board,position)
            if position_status == True:
                position_board(position,board,"X")

            turn="O"

        else:
            display_board(board)
            board_status=board_full(board,position_check)
            if winner_check(board, "X"):
                print("congrats {} is the winner".format(name["X"]))
                break
            if board_status:
                print("you tied")
                break
            position = player_input(board,name["O"])
            position_status = position_check(board,position)
            if position_status == True:
                 position_board(board,position,"O")

            turn="X"
```

The code should randomly pick the user who starts the game not X as always. Currently it does not get to the player inputs as it always shows a tie. I am hoping to later on add scores so the players can keep track on who has won the most games

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Please provide a minimal working example and describe the error and/or your problem in more details.

Comment: so far the choose player part works fine, it also chooses who goes first without any problem, it just does not get to the part where the players can play the game since it always sees a tie. I've copied a screen shot below of how it runs <br/> Enter your name Player1: 1 <br/> Enter your name Player2: 2 <br/>  What letter do you want to be?: X or O: x <br/>  Player1 is X player2 is O <br/>  player two starts <br/>  | | | | | | ......... | | | | | | ......... | | | | | |  <br/> you tied <br/> Enter your name Player1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error may be in the function `position_check`, where you check if the board position is equal to `""`, while you may want to check if it is still a space `" "`:

```
def position_check(board,position):
    if board[position] == "":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Change:

```
    if board[position] == "":
        return True
```

To:

```
    if board[position] == " ":
        return True
```

Tell me if this works ?